# Why are flash programmers using the SWF metatag if they can set the resolution in the .fla file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash application. The resolutions in the .fla file are 800 x 600. A friend of mine said I have to use the swf meta tag:

```
[SWF(width='800', height='600', backgroundColor='0x000000')]
```

It doesn't do anything to me. I don't understand why it is necessary. Please tell me why programmers put this command in their source code?

Comment: Personally, i love the AVM2 runtime and programming in ActionScript 3.0, but i loath the Flash Professional IDE and never use it. Of interest, you can also set the FPS in the swf metatag: `[SWF (width = 800, height = 600, backgroundColor = 0x000000, frameRate = 60)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the IDE and authoring tools used to develop Flash based applications.

#### Flash Builder

For developers using Flash Builder or equivalent IDE without the Flash Professional art board and document properties for authoring, the SWF meta tag is required to define attributes of the SWF.

```
package
{
    [SWF(percentWidth=100, percentHeight=100, backgroundColor=0x313131, frameRate=30)]
    public final class example extends Sprite
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

#### Flash Professional

Within Flash Professional, these are defined from the document properties.

[image: flash-properties]